# Get the empty records using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form on which I select different boxes and for each box there exists some records i-e (the number of openings of the box) in the database but it might be possible that for a selected box no records exists ie the box is not opened even single time. Currently when I select different boxes and if records not exist for a box it does not return even the empty array I want to it return even the empty results for the selected boxes. how can I achieve that? My query is

```
public function getBoxOpenings($boxes, $from_date, $to_date){
$query = $this->db->select('box_id, COUNT(box_id) AS Openings')
    ->from('mc_boxes_has_openings')
    ->where_in('box_id', $boxes)
    ->where('actiontime >=', $from_date)
    ->where('actiontime <=', $to_date)
    ->group_by('box_id')
    ->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
return $data;
}
```

Edit:

If I select 3 boxes and submit the form and records exists for only 2 boxes it returns something like this

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 12
        [location] => FRA-Air
        [Openings] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 14
        [location] => FRA-Hof
        [Openings] => 1
    )

)
```

How can I get all three records with one empty like this

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [mc_boxes_idmc_boxes] => 16
        [location] => Test
        [Openings] => 
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate more the question. Describe the table and what `box_id` represents...

Comment: @Fèlix Galindo Allué ok let me edit it

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué Kindly have alook at my edited question

Comment: I don't understand your select clause. It doesn't correspond to the samples you show. In the select appears the box_id field, and in the samples you show mcboxes_idmc_boxes and location...

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué Each time a box(page) is opened an entry is inserted in the table that box with some id is opened. Now if a box is opened 100 times there will be 100 entries with that box_id and i want to count them to get the number of opening times of a box ... Got it ?

Comment: I simply state that you do `select box_id` and `group by mcboxes_idmc_boxes`. That is what I don't understand. Is there a 1-to-1 relationship between those two field? And the field names are not the same in samples compared to code...

Comment: @Fèlix Galindo Allué ahhh actually they are same fields my bad i forgot to rename it as i did it in the start for simplicity. mcboxes_idmc_boxes is actually box_id

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just count whole records?

```
public function getBoxOpenings($boxes, $from_date, $to_date){
$query = $this->db->select('box_id, COUNT(*) AS Openings')
    ->from('mc_boxes_has_openings')
    ->where_in('box_id', $boxes)
    ->where('actiontime >=', $from_date)
    ->where('actiontime <=', $to_date)
    ->group_by('box_id')
    ->get();
$data = $query->result_array();
return $data;
}
```

Although I don't understand your group_by clause...

Comment: Different boxes have different openings so i have to count the openings of individual boxes